# How to change the data-target in bootstrap accordion dynamically according to ID

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have added mdb bootstrap accordion using jquery append inside a for loop. Each and every time when loop runs it creates an accordion panel with the same id and same data-target. The problem is because of same id and same data-target whenever I am clicking any one of the panels it opening all automatically.

```
$("#accordion").append('<div class="card w-100" id="'+["num"]+'"><div class="card-header" id="headingOne"><h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link p-0 text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">'+p[i]["jobtitle"]+'</button> </h5></div><div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion"><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text mb-0">Status</p>'+p[i]["status"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Job Id</p>'+p[i]["jobid"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Noc Code</p>'+p[i]["noc_code"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Job title</p>'+p[i]["jobtitle"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Location</p>'+p[i]["joblocation"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Business Name</p>'+p[i]["jobcompany"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Matches and report</p><p class="mb-0">12</p><p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Posting start date</p>'+p[i]["jobstartdate"]+'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">End date</p>'+p[i]["enddate"] +'<p class="card-text mb-0 mt-2">Operating name</p></div></div></div>');
```

I want to know how to write in data-target value same as id value

Comment: how about `data-target="#'+["num"]+'"`

Comment: Thank Carsten,  It Works